# cx_Freeze errors on OSX when freezeing PyQt5 application

Tags: python, macos, python-3.4, cx-freeze, pyqt5

I'm using cx_Freeze to freeze a PyQt5 python application and generate an OSX app bundle and I encountered the following problem:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cx_Freeze/freezer.py:590: UserWarning: Duplicate name: 'importlib/__init__.pyc'
outFile.writestr(zinfo, data)
copying /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so -> /Users/daniele/Documents/workspace/pygraphol/build/pyGraphol-0.1.0-gpl-darwin/PyQt5.QtCore.so
copying /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so -> /Users/daniele/Documents/workspace/pygraphol/build/pyGraphol-0.1.0-gpl-darwin/QtCore.so
copying /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore -> /Users/daniele/Documents/workspace/pygraphol/build/pyGraphol-0.1.0-gpl-darwin/QtCore
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore'
```

I'm using OSX Yosemite **10.10.4**, Python **3.4**, PyQt **5.5** built against Qt **5.5** using clang, cx_Freeze **4.3.4**. I had experiences of using cx_Freeze to freeze python 2.7 applications (using PyQt 5.4) in the past but never had this problem and it seems I cannot come up with a solution. I tried to search on SO and Google for a solution but I found problems which are similar to this one but the provided solutions do not work.

The problem is that this path `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/QtCore.framework` doesn't exists on my system. I don't think it's a Qt install issue since the application runs just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having same problem after updating from pyqt 5.3 to 5.5 . 
Mac 10.9, python 3.4 and (now) pyqt 5.5 / qt 5.5

Comment: I solved it by creating a softlink of all the Qt*.framework. Which means: `ln -s /path_to_qt/clang_64/lib/* .` from within `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/`

Comment: works! you should write it as an answer!

Comment: I don't know if it's a good solution since it sounds a bit hacky, that's why i didn't put it as an answer

Comment: @DanielePantaleone I have the same problem, would you please write your solution in more details?